# Android Development: Efficient Syntax Highlighting Tips?

Tags: android, performance, syntax, syntax-highlighting

I've developed my own syntax highlighting library for Android, and it works great, but the problem is it slows down the typing.

I've tried using an AsyncTask to perform the regular expressions in the background then apply the necassary colours but it still slowed down the typing process.

Currently, it reads the whole EditText, I thought of instead getting the line the text cursor is on, getting that lines CharSequence then performing the regular expressions on that line instead of the whole document, but I really don't know how I could get the line the user is working on :(.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're only doing single-line regexn/highlighting, your proposed strategy may not work. For example, you probably can't tell if you're in a multi-line comment without, well, scanning multiple lines. :-)

If you have not done so already, use Traceview to identify where the slowdowns are specifically. It may be that you can optimize enough other things. For example, maybe you're compiling all your `Pattern` objects on the fly rather than defining them statically.

Beyond that, I think a typical pattern is to only apply syntax highlighting when the user pauses. One possible way of implementing that would be:

Step #1: On every text change (which you have presumably already hooked into), `postDelayed()` a `Runnable` and save the timestamp retrieved from `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` in a data member of your `EditText` subclass (or wherever you have the syntax coloring logic). For the purposes of this answer, I'll call your delay period that you use with `postDelayed()` as `DELAY`.

Step #2: The `Runnable` compares the current time from `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` with the time of the last text change. If the time difference is less than `DELAY`, you know the user typed something in between when this `Runnable` was scheduled and now, so you just do nothing. If the time difference >= `DELAY`, though, you run through your syntax coloring logic.

This way, you skip applying the syntax coloring until the user pauses, thereby not interrupting their typing. You can tweak `DELAY`, or perhaps make it configurable.

BTW, you *are* planning on releasing this as an open source library, right? :-)

Comment: CommonsWare you're actually a life saver! Thank you so much, your answer is the perfect solution to my problem. I'm suprising there isn't loads of syntax highlighting libraries, it's pretty easy to do a decent one. To answer your question: well I'm making this library for use in my own app, so I'm not sure. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: @AlexPriceAP: "I'm suprising there isn't loads of syntax highlighting libraries, it's pretty easy to do a decent one" -- yeah, but we're all lazy... er, I mean... we want to promote reuse. :-)